# how can i use laravel code in java script

Tags: javascript, laravel

i want to translate button name in javascript by write laravel code

```
$(document).on('click', '.leave-edit-btn', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('leave-edit-btn').addClass('btn btn-white leave-cancel-btn').text("{{ __('trans.Edit') }}");
```

how can i do this?

(copied from comment):
this my code when i click on button no translation run

```
@section('scripts')
<script> 
$(document).on('click', '.leave-edit-btn', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('leave-edit-btn').addClass('btn btn-white leave-cancel-btn').text({{ __('trans.Save') }}); 
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Place your javascript inside a blade view

Comment: i want the same code now in blade but it not work

Comment: What does "_it not work_" mean? Blank page? Wrong translation? No translation? Do you get the correct translation when using `{{ __('trans.Edit') }}` outside of Javascript?

Comment: this my code when i click on button no translation run
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.leave-edit-btn', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('leave-edit-btn').addClass('btn btn-white leave-cancel-btn').text({{ __('trans.Save') }});
  
 
 });
        
    </script>
@endsection

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, hard to read/follow. Instead, [edit] your question and paste it there, then remove the comment. Thanks

Comment: thanks i will set it in another question

Comment: Really no need for another question, you can edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

<del>based on the comments, are you sure your file is `*.blade.php` not just `*.php`? and it need to be under `resources/view` and use it as a view</del>

are you sure your js is actually works? like the `.leave-edit-btn` is exists

You may try this btw

```php
@section('scripts')
<script> 
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(document).on('click', '.leave-edit-btn', function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('leave-edit-btn').addClass('btn btn-white leave-cancel-btn').text(@json(__('trans.Save'))); 
  });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i cant add a comment yet tho, so i can just do this

Comment: This does still not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: yes iam sure of that

Comment: can you inspect into the final document source see whether this whole script tag exists or not, if not then you are missing a `@yield('scripts')` in your layout

Answer (score 0):

Using `.text(text)` to set an elements text requires the parameter to be a `string`. Use quotes around `{{ __('trans.Save') }}` like so:

```
@section('scripts')
<script> 
$(document).on('click', '.leave-edit-btn', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('leave-edit-btn').addClass('btn btn-white leave-cancel-btn').text("{{ __('trans.Save') }}"); 
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it when you can so it can be closed. Thanks